# A problem about ring isomorphism?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ring-homomorphism, ring-isomorphism

> problem:let $R$ and $R'$ be commutative rings,and let $I⊆R$ and $I'⊆R'$ be ideals.
> if $f:R→R'$ is homomorphism with $f(I)⊆I'$,prove that :
> (i)$f_*:r+I→f(r)+I'$ is well-defined  homomorphism $f_*:R/I→R'/I'$
> (ii)If $f$ is isomorphism,then $f_*$ is also.

**My attempt**:
For(i) I use condition $f(I)⊆I'$ to prove $f*$ is well-defined, and the homomorphism of $f_*$can derived by homomorphism $f$.
For(ii) i don't know how to do it.Because i think (ii)  is wrong. We know $ker f_*=\{r:f_*(r)=0 \}=\{r:f(r)+I'=I' \}=\{r:f(r)∈I' \}=f^{-1}(I')$.

If $ f_*$ is isomorphism,then $ker f_*=f^{-1}(I')=\{0\}$,but $f$ is also isomorphism,then $I'=0$.

Comment: Like you suspect, (ii) is false. For example, take $R = R' = \mathbb{Z}$, $f = \operatorname{id}_{\mathbb{Z}}$, $I = 0$, $I' = 2\mathbb{Z}$. Then $f$ is an isomorphism but $f_* : \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ cannot be.

Comment: Yes, part (ii) is false as stated. If $R=R'=\mathbb{Z}$ and $I=(n)$, $I'=(m)$ with $m \mid n \in \mathbb{Z}$, then the identity map $f:R \to R'$ satisfies $f(I) \subseteq (I')$, hence descends to $f_*: R/I \to R'/I'$, but this homomorphism is not an isomorphism unless $m=n$.

Comment: Thanks,if we have $f(I)=f(I')$,(ii) is ture,

Comment: This problem comes from Rotman advanced morden algebra 3rd, i already meet some mistakes.

Comment: To help with your intuition, a smaller ideal produces a larger quotient (fewer ring element are identified with one another via the equivalence). In order for a homomorphism to be well-defined, you need to quotient by *more* (i.e. a larger ideal) and map to a smaller quotient ring, hence the necessary condition that $f(I) \subseteq I'$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, $$\ker f_* = \{r+I : r \in R,\, f(r)+I' = I'\} = \{r+I : r \in f^{-1}(I')\} = f^{-1}(I')/I$$ and note that $f_*$ is surjective if and only if for each $r' \in R'$ there exists $r \in R$ such that $r'+I' = f(r)+I'$, that is, if for each $r' \in R'$ there exists $r \in R$ such that $r'-f(r) \in I'$.

Thus, we see that

- $f_*$ is injective iff $I = f^{-1}(I')$; and
- $f_*$ is surjective iff $R' = \operatorname{im} f + I'$.